# Making an AJAX call to update the database onChange of a textarea

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a feature on my website that automatically updates the database onchange of the textarea below (which is going to be act as a 'post-it note for reminders'). I am new to ajax, and I was wondering if someone can show me a basic example of how I would make an AJAX call to update my database onChange of the textarea below?

```
<?php
//Create mysql connect variable
$conn = mysql_connect('samplesource.com', 'example', 'pass');

//kill connection if error occurs
if(!$conn){
    die('Error: Unable to connect.' . '<br>' . mysql_error());
}
//connect to mysql database
mysql_select_db("mydb", $conn);

session_start();
$userid = $_SESSION['id'];

$results = ("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE userid='$userid'");
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>practice</title>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $(".sometext").change(function(){   
        //make ajax call to update database onChange    
    }); 
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>

<textarea class="note" style="resize:none; width:300px; height:200px;"> </textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can read http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, what is the problem?

Comment: As an aside, you may want to (re)set a timer with a small delay (~150ms?) via setTimeout on the textarea's onchange event to avoid per-keystroke database calls.

Comment: @Raminson, posting a link without any explanation is useless.

Comment: I'm assuming you meant to put `$(document).ready(` instead of `$(document).change(`, right? And do you want to update the database on change or on blur? Your code doesn't match the question you are asking

Comment: @MrOBrian I apologize, I fixed the mistake. I would like to update onChange

Comment: @MHZ it sounds someone has downvoted 2 questions of mine, note that I haven't downvoted your question.

Comment: I agree with @Raminson that you should go read the documentation on jQuery's ajax call. We'll help you fix code that you can't get working, but don't rely on the community to write your code for you

Comment: We'll im trying to create some sample code to start out, so I can understand enough to implement it. Not expecting for anyone to write my code just walk me through a basic example... didn't think I'm in the wrong for asking such a question... The link @Raminson provided is not really helpful without an explanation, I can comment on everyones questions and say "Why not read Java For Beginners" for the answer and provide a link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you'd need to move your database save script into a new file e.g save.php

On your `<textarea>` i'd add

```
<textarea onchange="saveChanges(this);"></textarea>
```

For the javascript save function that's called when a change is made:

```
function saveChanges(object){   
    $.ajax({
        url: 'save.php',
        data: 'content=' + object.value,
        cache: false,
        error: function(e){
            alert(e);
        },
        success: function(response){
            // A response to say if it's updated or not
            alert(response);
        }
    });   
}
```

This is a very quick and dirty way of doing it.